# how to load weight keras model from URL

Tags: python, url, keras, deep-learning, model

I have trained my Keras model in google colab and saved the model as model.h5 file in google drive. I made the model.5 file accessible through a public URL. Now I want to load the model with load_model() from this URL. I am getting an error *File system scheme 'https' not implemented 
Here is my code.

```
model=load_model(url)
```

It would great if I could get a possible solution for this.